# Oracle 11.2.0.3 Service Name Mismatch issue

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

### My Environment

During Installation

SID  lab3

Service_Name  lab3.domain.com

### Changes

Some time ago I changed my service_name to just lab3 to match my SID

Select instance_name from v$instance;

lab3

Select value from v$parameter where name like '%service_name%';

lab3

### Issue

when i try to connect from my application
jdbc:mercury:oracle://192.168.1.203:1521;servicename=lab3 ***doesn't work***

jdbc:mercury:oracle://192.168.1.203:1521;servicename=lab3.domain.com ***works while this is not my service name anymore***

My application doesn't require any oracle client installed so there is no tons file or anything else on the client side. it's all on server side

### Error in Application Logs

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Mercury][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-12514 Connection refused, the specified service name (lab3) was not recognized by the Oracle server. at com.mercury.jdbc.oraclebase.ddcr.b(Unknown Source) at com.mercury.jdbc.oraclebase.ddcr.a(Unknown Source) at

### lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on 06-MAR-2016 20:34:40
Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))

### STATUS of the LISTENER

Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
Start Date                06-MAR-2016 20:02:45
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 32 min. 21 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\oracle\Administrator\product\11.2.0\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oracle\Administrator\diag\tnslsnr\Lab3\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=Lab3.domain.com)(PORT=1521)))

Services Summary...

Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...

Service "lab3.domain.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "lab3", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...

Service "lab3XDB.domain.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "lab3", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

### SQL> show parameter db_domain;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE

---

db_domain                            string      domain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SERVICE_NAME is made up of the values db_unique_name and db_domain parameters. Here is the reference to Oracle Documentation about [SERVICE_NAME](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams217.htm).
 Even if you set lab3 as service name oracle automatically adds value of db_domain on it. Your service_name is 'lab3' and db_domain is 'domain.com' so you end up with the orgianl service name.
Instead you can create tns service name to point that service. Example is given below

```
lab3 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = domain.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = lab3.domain.com)
    )
  )
```

Then you can use this tnsname(lab3).